# Should I par-boil my pickled potatoes before roasting them?

Tags: potatoes, fermentation, pickling, french-fries, chips

I am attempting to make some pickled fries, similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnRvRDUtgY4

However, I don't have a frier (nor do I want to fry on the stove top), so I was thinking of cooking them in the oven like I do usually with potato wedges - par boil for 5 mins, season, then add to roasting tin with hot oil.

This yields nice crunchy wedges.

My question then - my potatoes are pickled, should I par boil them before I put them in the oven? Or will this in some way... de-pickle them?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't "de-pickle" them (I'm fairly certain there's no way to accomplish that) but you should definitely par boil them shorter than you normally would because they will be somewhat softened by the pickling already.